Rust mismatch between input and output types of trait object
So my issue is that I have a layer trait with input and output types as follows:
pub trait Layer {
    type Input: Dimension;
    type Output: Dimension;
    
    fn forward(&mut self, input: &ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, Self::Input>) -> ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, Self::Output>;
}

With this forward function:
impl<A: Activation> Layer for DenseLayer<A> {
    type Input = Ix2;
    type Output = Ix2;

    fn forward(&mut self, input: &Array2<f32>) -> Array2<f32> {
        assert_eq!(input.shape()[1], self.weights.shape()[0], "Input width must match weight height.");
        let z = input.dot(&self.weights) + &self.biases;

        self.activation.activate(&z)
    }
}

I have these so that my forward or backwards functions can take in for example an array of 2 dimensions but still output one with only 1 dimension.
Then I have an implementation for a sort of wrapper of this layer trait where I want to forward through all the layers:
pub struct NeuralNetwork<'a, L>
where
    L: Layer + 'a,
{
    layers: Vec<L>,
    loss_function: &'a dyn Cost,
}

impl<'a, L> NeuralNetwork<'a, L>
where
    L: Layer + 'a,
{
    pub fn new(layers: Vec<L>, loss_function: &'a dyn Cost) -> Self {
        NeuralNetwork { layers, loss_function }
    }

    pub fn forward(&mut self, input: &ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, L::Input>) -> ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, L::Output> {
        let mut output = input.clone();

        // todo fix the layer forward changing input to output
        // causing mismatch in the input and output dimensions of forward
        for layer in &mut self.layers {
            output = layer.forward(&output);
        }

        output
    }
}

Now because in the for loop I first input of type input, then receive output from layer.forward. In the next iteration it takes the type output, but the layer.forward only accepts type input. Atleast that is what I think is happening.
This might seem like a really simple issue but I am genuinly unsure on how to fix this.
Edit 1:
Reproduceable Example:
use ndarray::{Array, Array2, ArrayBase, Dimension, OwnedRepr};

pub trait Layer {
    type Input: Dimension;
    type Output: Dimension;

    fn forward(&mut self, input: &ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, Self::Input>) -> ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, Self::Output>;
}

// A Dense Layer struct
pub struct DenseLayer {
    weights: Array2<f32>,
    biases: Array2<f32>,
}

impl DenseLayer {
    pub fn new(input_size: usize, output_size: usize) -> Self {
        let weights = Array::random((input_size, output_size), rand::distributions::Uniform::new(-0.5, 0.5));
        let biases = Array::zeros((1, output_size));
        DenseLayer { weights, biases }
    }
}

impl Layer for DenseLayer {
    type Input = ndarray::Ix2;  // Two-dimensional input
    type Output = ndarray::Ix2; // Two-dimensional output

    fn forward(&mut self, input: &ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, Self::Input>) -> ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, Self::Output> {
        assert_eq!(input.shape()[1], self.weights.shape()[0], "Input width must match weight height.");
        let z = input.dot(&self.weights) + &self.biases;
        z // Return the output directly without activation
    }
}

// Neural Network struct
pub struct NeuralNetwork<'a, L>
where
    L: Layer + 'a,
{
    layers: Vec<L>,
}

impl<'a, L> NeuralNetwork<'a, L>
where
    L: Layer + 'a,
{
    pub fn new(layers: Vec<L>) -> Self {
        NeuralNetwork { layers }
    }

    pub fn forward(&mut self, input: &ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, L::Input>) -> ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f32>, L::Output> {
        let mut output = input.clone();

        for layer in &mut self.layers {
            output = layer.forward(&output);
        }

        output
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Create a neural network with one Dense Layer
    let mut dense_layer = DenseLayer::new(3, 2);
    let mut nn = NeuralNetwork::new(vec![dense_layer]);

    // Create an example input (1 batch, 3 features)
    let input = Array::from_shape_vec((1, 3), vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).unwrap();
    
    // Forward pass
    let output = nn.forward(&input);
    println!("Output: {:?}", output);
}



Please create a [mre]. There are a ton of missing type definitions.

Forget the loop — what should layer.forward(input) do? Sounds like you need a first layer and layers 2..n separately.

Sorry @cdhowie, I added an example which should work

@BallpointBen layer.forward(input) is supposed to take an array with specified input amounts and output an array with specific amounts. I added an example which should hopefully be more clear. If there's still anything missing or you have any questions let me know.

There's two things you need to get NeuralNetwork::forward to compile.

You need to restrict the Layer bound so that the Input and Output associated types are the same type.
You need to ensure that this type implements Clone so that input.clone() can clone the underlying array instead of cloning the reference.

These bounds will communicate these restrictions to the compiler (note the introduction of a new generic parameter T on the impl block):
impl<'a, L, T> NeuralNetwork<'a, L>
where
    L: Layer<Input = T, Output = T> + 'a,
    T: Clone,

Note that you should consider moving NeuralNetwork::new to an impl block with minimal restrictions, as there's no reason it needs these restrictions applied to it.

There are a few other compile-time errors but I assume these are unrelated to the problem you're trying to solve.  In particular, it's not clear to me why you have a 'a lifetime on NeuralNetwork; you can remove it completely and the code still compiles.

Thanks! I do believe this to have fixed this specific error. Though I am now encountering another one related to smth not present in the example and activations. I'm gonna update the example to try and encapsulate that error. The reason I have the 'a lifetime in the first place is because of another trait I have in my original struct, which stores the cost function of the network and handling that dynamicaly, I see how that's confusing in the example. Also could you explain how I could move the NeuralNetwork::new to another impl block?

@NLion74 If you have another issue then please open a new question. Each SO question should address a single issue. To deal with the new function just create a new impl block for NeuralNetwork and only add the bounds that are required for it to compile. Generally speaking, you should not put unnecessary bounds on functions or structs as this can interfere with generic usage.
